# System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url") VS System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir")

Tags: url, properties, jboss, config, dir

I want to deploy a pre compiled EAR on openshift.com but sadly I get some exceptions.

In the logs I can see that the line:

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url")
```

returns a null

But when I print out the line (only for testing)

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir")
```

Im getting a path.

The funny part is that my local computer (JBossAS 5) prints out the opposite:
`System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url")` -> path
`System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir")` -> null

So is there any way how I can set the config.url?
And is there any differences between these two properties?
If yes, I could easily replace the line, but otherwise I don't want two different EAR's 
(local and openshift.com).

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable. I would try calling system.getenv without a parameter to get the full mapping then scan through that and see what it contains. Also make sure the environment variable is set globally (or at least in the context where you are executing.)

Map mp = System.getenv();

mp.get("JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR")+"/"+filename